# sql to get data uptil every last Sunday dynamically

Tags: teradata

Please,I'm trying to select data from a table in SQL teradata up to last Sunday.
At a particular time, i want to be able to retrieve records until last week Sunday dynamically.
Date should be <= 12/08/18 (Last week Sunday date )
Thank you very much

Comment: It's Teradata SQL please

Answer (score 1):

You can find the next Sunday/Monday and subtract 7 days to get the previous one, logic depends on what you want to return for a Sunday:

```
where mycol <  Next_Day(current_date, 'mon')-7   -- Sunday 2018-08-19 -> 2018-08-19 = current Sunday
where mycol <= Next_Day(current_date, 'sun')-7   -- Sunday 2018-08-19 -> 2018-08-12 = previous Sunday
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I used your script like this in Teradata: order_date < = Next_Day(calendar_date, 'sun')-7  and I'm getting some error message: expected something between '< and '='. Sorry i'm new to teradata and thank you for your help

Comment: No blank between `<` and `=` , it's `<=`

Comment: Thank you again. But i still got this error message that the column calendar_date does not exist in the database?